# How would I round two separate parts of a coordinates string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string  `58.1365784, 17.1916815` which is some lat lng data. What I'd like returned is the both coords but rounded to 4 decimal places, like this `58.1365, 17.1916`. If it were just one number I could do `x.round(4)`, but this obviously gets rid of the other part of the string...

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
coords = '58.1365784, 17.1916815'
coords.split(', ').map { |e| e.to_f.round(4) }
```

It returns an array of floats rounded to the fourth decimal:

```
#=> [58.1366, 17.1917]
```

It works using **split** (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-split) to return an array of two strings, then **map** (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map) to convert to float and round.

If you want back the string, just add `.join(', ')` at the end:

```
#=> "58.1366, 17.1917"
```